# Get selected values of JSON response c# on unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to JSON and I need to get selected values out of a JSON response.this is my code below please help me i use narrativa covid19 api

https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-03-22/country/:countryname "

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-03-22/country/" + "us");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Debug.Log(response.Content);
            string jsonStringDet = responseCountries.Content;
             Rootobject myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonStringDet);
```

and this is my class i use past special to get this class on visula studio from this link

https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-11-02/country/us

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Dates dates { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public Total total { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
}

public class Dates
{
    public _20201102 _20201102 { get; set; }
}

public class _20201102
{
    public Countries countries { get; set; }
    public Info info { get; set; }
}

public class Countries
{
    public US US { get; set; }
}

public class US
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Link[] links { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public Region[] regions { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public int today_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_new_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int today_new_recovered { get; set; }
    public int today_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int today_recovered { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_open_cases { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Link1[] links { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public Sub_Regions[] sub_regions { get; set; }
    public int today_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_new_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int today_new_recovered { get; set; }
    public int today_new_tests { get; set; }
    public int today_new_total_hospitalised_patients { get; set; }
    public int today_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int today_recovered { get; set; }
    public int today_tests { get; set; }
    public int today_total_hospitalised_patients { get; set; }
    public float? today_vs_yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public float? today_vs_yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_open_cases { get; set; }
    public float? today_vs_yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_tests { get; set; }
    public float? today_vs_yesterday_total_hospitalised_patients { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_tests { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_total_hospitalised_patients { get; set; }
}

public class Link1
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Sub_Regions
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public int today_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_new_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_recovered { get; set; }
    public int today_recovered { get; set; }
    public float? today_vs_yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public float? today_vs_yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public object today_vs_yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string date_generation { get; set; }
    public string yesterday { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string by { get; set; }
    public string[] url { get; set; }
}

public class Total
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string rid { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public int today_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int today_new_deaths { get; set; }
    public int today_new_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int today_new_recovered { get; set; }
    public int today_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int today_recovered { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_open_cases { get; set; }
    public float today_vs_yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_confirmed { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_deaths { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_open_cases { get; set; }
    public int yesterday_recovered { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should correctly create classes that represent your response, for that, I would recommend this site that will help with that:
   (https://json2csharp.com/)
2. you are not using correctly RestSharp, you can use use the generic version of **Execute** that accept the model to parse the sent json

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-03-22/country/" + "us");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<Rootobject>(request)?.Data;
```

to access your Dates object, you only need to do so,

```
var dates  = response?.dates
```

Comment: I try this but i not working and Yes I use https://json2csharp.com/ and  allways i have this error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: If you are using the site that I mentionned then please the coversion with attributes. if you used my code there is no way that you have a null reference exception.

Comment: yes it work but my problem is how to select data from the response result

Comment: you already have your response casted to your model, so you can access its properties.

Comment: I got this error  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
test.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/test.cs:40)

Comment: I updates my answer, I gave you an example to follow it

Comment: the data from                                                                                                                       -metadata ,total,updated_at it working but from dates it not workink and i  got this error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: the data from -metadata ,total,updated_at it working but from dates it not workink and i got this error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: please regenerate your object from the site I gave in my answer, try to use attributes

Comment: yes i use https://json2csharp.com/ ,please tell me wath you mean ,try to use attributes ???

Comment: before clic the button to convert, you have checkboxes to use a conversion  with jsonattribute, use it

Comment: The statement contains 5 returned objects, and 1 of them can throw NullReferenceException  ,this objects (dates)

Comment: dates is a list, so before using each item from it, you have to check first if it is null or not.

Comment: i check dates is null onr not and i got null on reference on dates

Comment: please let me see the statment your write to get dates

Comment: var today_confirmed = response?.dates.date.countries.US.today_confirmed;

Comment: dates is a list, so you need to access items by index, or using a loop ,
for example 
```
ar today_confirmed = response?.dates?.date[0].countries.US.today_confirmed
```

Comment: No on my class it not a list